# The updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement needs to be reviewed

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload to Apple with our Code, but Apple is preventing us from doing so. We have accepted the agreement but App Store Connect still doesn't reflect this.

My Account Holder tried both developer.apple.com and https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/ but is getting different results: developer site shows she accepted the most recent agreement, but appstoreconnect shows she hasn't and isn't letting her accept the agreement from her side.

Is there anything special that needs to be done to resolve this?

Comment: What did Apple say when you asked them?

Comment: That is still being investigated at this stage, The Account Holder is on the phone with them now. They think it may be on their end, but I am trying to do due diligence and confirm whether there is any step on our end that hasn't been done yet.